# Issue with aligning the container to the right of main container with full height

Tags: javascript, html, css

Struggling to find a solution for an SO question I stuck in a wired issue I can't handle without a hand:

```css
/*Explain Bubble*/
.explainer-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*height: 47vh;*/
  top: 9vw;
  z-index: 11;

  max-width: 70vw;
  max-height: 47vh;
  background-color: rgba(6, 0, 15, 0.6);
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 1.25vw;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 0.0625rem 0.125rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.explain-header {
  padding: 1.2em 1em;
  color: #e9e4f0;
}
#phrase {
   font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
   color: #ff9100;
}
#colon {
  font-family: "Vazir-Bold";
  color: #ff0033;
}
#en-definition{
  font-family: "Open Sans Light";
   color: #f0ede9;
}
#title-synonym {
  font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
  font-size: 1vw;
   color: #4287f5;
}
#synonym {
   font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
   font-size: 1vw;
   color: #b0bfd9;
}
.sample-sentence {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: start;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.rtl-sample  {
  font-family: "Vazir-Thin";
  font-size: 0.9vw;
  margin-top: 1vh;
   margin-bottom: 0;
  direction: rtl;

}
.eng-sample {
  font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  color: #eee6f0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/*Explain Styles*/
.rtl-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 35vw;
  max-height: 47vh;
  width: 40vw;
  z-index: 11;
  outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
  float: right;
  top: -10vw;
}

.rtl-explain {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir-Thin";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
    opacity: 0;  
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="explainer-container">

        <div class="explain-header">
            <span id="phrase">to make up for</span>
            <span id="colon">:</span>
            <span id="en-definition">to prepare for sth</span>
            <br>
            <span id="title-synonym">synonym(s):</span>
            <span id="synonym">to prepare - to plan</span>

            <div class="sample-sentence">
              <p class="eng-sample">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
              <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخواب روی کاناپه برات آماده می کنم.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="sample-sentence">
              <p class="eng-sample">I on the sofa.</p>
              <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخه می کنم.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="sample-sentence">
              <p class="eng-sample">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
              <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخواب روی کاناپه برات آماده می کنم.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="sample-sentence">
              <p class="eng-sample">I on the sofa.</p>
              <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخه می کنم.</p>
            </div>


            <div class="rtl-container">
                <p id="rtl-explain" class="rtl-explain captionShow"><ul><li>بهترین روش برای ما استفاده از این <span class="colored">I</span> <span class="colored">will</span> <span class="colored">be</span> <span class="colored">+</span> <span class="colored">ing</span> هست.</li><li>در تمام این روش ها ما داریم از <span class="colored">رنگ های مختلف</span> استفاده   می کنیم. به امید دیدار... <span class="round-bracket">( </span>ارادتمند شما<span class="round-bracket"> )</span></li><li>ادامه دارد این ماجرا</li></ul></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

I want the `rtl-container` div align to the top-right of the main container full height like this:

[image]

So far I need to give the `rtl-container` style of `top: -10vw;` to see it...

Comment: Instead of `top: -10vw;` why not use flexbox?

Comment: Hello. Flexbox can solve your problem. Use this.

Comment: How should I use it? How can I align it to right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `position: absolute;` instead of `position: relative;` and add `right: 0px; top: 0px;` in your `.rtl-container`.

```css
/*Explain Bubble*/
.explainer-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 47vh;
    top: 9vw;
    z-index: 11;

    max-width: 70vw;
    max-height: 47vh;
    background-color: rgba(6, 0, 15, 0.6);
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.25vw;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    box-shadow: 0 0.125rem 0.5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 0.0625rem 0.125rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.explain-header {
    padding: 1.2em 1em;
    color: #e9e4f0;
}

#phrase {
    font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
    color: #ff9100;
}

#colon {
    font-family: "Vazir-Bold";
    color: #ff0033;
}

#en-definition {
    font-family: "Open Sans Light";
    color: #f0ede9;
}

#title-synonym {
    font-family: "Open Sans Bold";
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #4287f5;
}

#synonym {
    font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #b0bfd9;
}

.sample-sentence {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: start;
    max-width: 50%;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.rtl-sample {
    font-family: "Vazir-Thin";
    font-size: 0.9vw;
    margin-top: 1vh;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    direction: rtl;

}

.eng-sample {
    font-family: "Open Sans Regular";
    font-size: 1.2vw;
    color: #eee6f0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}


/*Explain Styles*/
.rtl-container {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 35vw;
    max-height: 47vh;
    width: 40vw;
    z-index: 11;
    outline: 0.1vw dashed orange;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}

.rtl-explain {
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Vazir-Thin";
    direction: rtl;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: rgb(248, 247, 250);
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="explainer-container">

    <div class="explain-header">
        <span id="phrase">to make up for</span>
        <span id="colon">:</span>
        <span id="en-definition">to prepare for sth</span>
        <br>
        <span id="title-synonym">synonym(s):</span>
        <span id="synonym">to prepare - to plan</span>

        <div class="sample-sentence">
            <p class="eng-sample">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
            <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخواب روی کاناپه برات آماده می کنم.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sample-sentence">
            <p class="eng-sample">I on the sofa.</p>
            <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخه می کنم.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sample-sentence">
            <p class="eng-sample">I could make up a bed for you on the sofa.</p>
            <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخواب روی کاناپه برات آماده می کنم.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sample-sentence">
            <p class="eng-sample">I on the sofa.</p>
            <p class="rtl-sample">ی رختخه می کنم.</p>
        </div>


        <div class="rtl-container">
            <p id="rtl-explain" class="rtl-explain captionShow">
                <ul>
                    <li>بهترین روش برای ما استفاده از این <span class="colored">I</span> <span
                            class="colored">will</span> <span class="colored">be</span> <span
                            class="colored">+</span> <span class="colored">ing</span> هست.</li>
                    <li>در تمام این روش ها ما داریم از <span class="colored">رنگ های مختلف</span> استفاده می کنیم.
                        به امید دیدار... <span class="round-bracket">( </span>ارادتمند شما<span
                            class="round-bracket"> )</span></li>
                    <li>ادامه دارد این ماجرا</li>
                </ul>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think we need relative position in order to fit the explainer-container when `rtl-container` gets bigger... I mean I want to increase height of the `explainer-container` if `rtl-container` gets bigger...

Comment: No need to do that, you can check by increasing `rtl-container`'s height. Since it's in the `explainer-container`, the absolute position of `rtl-container` will make the container within.

Comment: No... I mean if for instance we have more than 10 `li`s in `rtl-container` at 5th one it overflows with the `explainer-container` and we can not see the remaining anymore...

Comment: You can use scroll then, just instead of `overflow: hidden;`, use `overflow: auto;`. Then if contents are exceeded the main container's height, it will show the rest of them by scrolling.